# Fiddler showing cache hits?

Tags: caching, fiddler, http-caching

I just wanted to check if my HTTP caching for my website is working especially since I moved to a CDN.

Now I used both Fiddler and Firebug and what I am seeing is that requests for ALL scripts and images on my page every time I navigate to it. Response code is 200.

If I open the page in Chrome, the developer tools also show me all these requests but Chrome also tells me that the requests are served from the Cache. Chrome requests are not listed in Fiddler (while FF and IE requests are).

My original assumption was that if Firefox or Internet Explorer get a file from their cache that request wouldn't show up at all in Fiddler.

I checked my caching headers and since Chrome behaved exactly like I expected I am asking myself if my assumption about Fiddler was wrong. Are FF/IE behaving differently when Fiddler is started? Is Fiddler showing cache hits?

Answer (score 3):

As a network proxy, Fiddler is not able to show anything that comes out of the cache. If you see a request in Fiddler, then that request was sent over the wire.

One thing to keep in mind is that if you're refreshing the page (e.g. with the button or F5) then the cache can be bypassed; see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/07/08/technical-information-about-conditional-http-requests-and-the-refresh-button.aspx

Comment: Local cache or server cache? 304's are cached responses right?

Comment: @Ethan I want to check the local cache. I don't get ANY 304s, all answers are 200.

Comment: MSFT- : I am aware of the F5 key. I just did a test with the Stackoverflow site and Fiddler and FF4. So, in the header of this page I have my username. When I click on it, I see in Fiddler requests for favicon.ico and jquery and all.css. If I click the link again (not F5), I see the same requests again. So, is jquery loaded from Google's server for every page I am calling here? I hope not. So, why are these requests listed in Fiddler???

Comment: Do you get 200 from google/stackoverflow as well? I haven't used fiddler, but all browsers must send requests regardless of what they have in cache. They just include a header asking if the server version is modified since time of the cached version. server could then respond with 304 (Not Modified).

Comment: This "all browsers must send requests regardless of what they have in cache." is incorrect. A Conditional Request (eligible for 304 response) is only sent if the cached version isn't known to be fresh. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx for more information.